# How to add FastClick to Next.JS?

Tags: next.js

When I try to modify `pages/_document.js` to add the FastClick event registration (see below) it complains that `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. I guess it's because it's executed on the server and the `document` is not defined there. Any way to resolve it?

```
if ('addEventListener' in document) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body)
  }, false)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pages/_document.js` only rendered on server according to `next.js` [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-document).

I suggest to use that code in `pages/_app.js` which will be shared between all components.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `process.browser` to make sure your code is being executed in the front end only.

```
if (process.browser) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body)
  }, false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. It still says `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: Can you provide your full _document.js file?

Comment: Sure, I just pasted the code you provided, here it is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVPNzX

Comment: I think the answer from Moho already answered your error, you should not put that function in _document.js